# Como recuperar valores de duas tabelas em Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

é a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta aqui, e estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade.

Estou fazendo meu TCC de info, é um site para os alunos e tal... é como se fosse o Facebook sacas? 
Travei na parte onde o PHP recupera os dados da tabela 'post' do Mysql para aparecer na linha do tempo.

Tentei assim :

```
SELECT * FROM `usuario`, `post` WHERE `usuario`.`id` = '[ID_DO_USUÁRIO]'
```

E usando o Var_dump() do PHP me aparece este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou recendo todos os dados do usuário sem necessidade, onde o que eu só queria fosse o nome, sobre_nome, e alguns argumentos...

Dai então tentei assim:

(Devo ter faltado nesta aula kk)

```
SELECT `id`, `nome`, `sobre_nome`, `foto` FROM `usuario`, SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `usuario`.`id` = '9223372036854775807'
```

E me da este erro:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `usuario`.`id` = '9223372036854775807' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Se vocês perceberam, no resultado do Var_dump... eu recebo dois resultados que é equivalente ao ID do usuário (desnecessário)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso pessoal, não sei se vão pegar a logica, mas eu simplesmente quero pegar alguns (não todos) os argumentos da tabela 'usuário' e da tabela 'posts' sem ter que fazer 2 Querys(não sei se é assim que fala...).

Resumindo, Socorro kk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode usar o JOIN para juntar os resultado das duas tabelas 
antes do from você especifica todas as colunas que você quer como retorno.

SELECT id, nome, sobre_nome, foto FROM post INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.id = post.id_usuario_post WHERE usuario.id = 9223372036854775807

Saiba mais.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, você quer relacionar essas duas tabelas.

Então você pode usar o inner join na consulta, como por exemplo:

```
SELECT nome, sobre_nome, foto
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN post ON usuario.id = post.idusuario;
```

Da uma olhada ai para você entender melhor: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Valeu cara, testei e deu certo!